# How to autostart Linux service after reboot if a condition is met?

Tags: linux, rpm-spec, autostart, systemctl

How can I please auto start a Linux service after system reboot, but only if a certain file exists?

This is what I have so far, which does not auto-start the service on reboot:

In the `MyService.spec` file:

```
systemctl enable MyService
if [[ -f $FILE ]]; then
    systemctl start MyService
fi
```

I have also created the `MyService.service` file which correctly contains the `ExecStart` directive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change `ExecStart` in `MyService.service` to be conditional with bash. for example:

`ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '[ -f file_path ] && MyService_Binary'`

It will start the service if `file_path` exists.